# What is the benefit of using type-safe collection classes?

Tags: c#, collections, type-safety

I was wondering, why on some occasions i see a class representing some type's collection.

For example:

In Microsoft XNA Framework: TextureCollection, TouchCollection, etc.
Also other classes in the .NET framework itself, ending with Collection.

Why is it designed this way? what are the benefits for doing it this way and not as a generic type collection, like was introduced in C# 2.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples you gave are good ones.  TextureCollection is sealed and has no public constructor, only an internal one.  TouchCollection implements `IList<TouchLocation>`, similar to the way `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`.  Generics at work here btw, the upvoted answer isn't correct.

TextureCollection is intentionally crippled, it makes sure that you can never create an instance of it.  Only *secret knowledge* about textures can fill this collection, a List<> wouldn't suffice since it cannot be initialized with that secret knowledge that makes the indexer work.  Nor does the class *need* to be generic, it only knows about Texture class instances.

The TouchCollection is similarly specialized.  The Add() method throws a NotSupportedException.  This cannot be done with a regular List<> class, its Add() method isn't virtual so cannot be overridden to throw the exception.

This is not unusual.

Comment: What do u mean by secret knowledge?

Answer (score 3):

In the .NET framework itself, many type-safe collections predate 2.0 Generics, and are kept for compatibility.

For several XAML-related contexts, there's either no syntax to specify a generic class, or the syntax is cumbersome. Therefore, when `List<T>` wiould be used, there's a specific `TList` written for each need.

Comment: XNA uses generics, the OP's example of TouchCollection implements `IList<TouchLocation>`.

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to define your own semantics on the collection (you may not want to have an `Add` or `AddRange` method etc...).

Additionally, readability is increased by not having your code littered with `List<Touch>` and `List<Texture>` everywhere.

There is also quite a lot of .NET 1.0/1.1 code that still needs to work, so the older collections that predate generics still need to exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to use generic classes in XAML for example.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Oded's answer, your own class type allows for much easier change down the track when you decide you want a stack / queue etc instead of that `List`. There can be lots of reasons for this, including performance, memory use etc.

In fact, it's usually a good idea to hide that type of implementation detail - users of your class just want to know that it stores `Textures`, not how.